# Placing elements in layout file

Tags: android

I want to design a screen as below, I am trying to display the TOTAL and other data next to it.I am not getting how to display it exactly in the screen.
[image]

the layout file is

```
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:divider="#00000000"
            android:dividerHeight="5dp"
           />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Total"
                />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:text="Comment" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Comment goes here"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

I want to display GT, FSP, DIS % and Discount as shown in image

Comment: Please explain more....

Comment: I want to display the Total section above comment part ,has in you can see in my layout i have just display the title TOTAL but i am not able to display the data GT,FSP...,just the design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a TableLayout to display your GT,FSP ,DIS % and Discount TextView, and place this TableLayout in a LinearLayout (with horizontal orientation) with your Total TextView, like :

```
<LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Total"/>

   <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

           <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="GT :"/>

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_gt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="54000"/>

           <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Dis % :"/>

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_dis"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="29.15"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

           <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="FSP :"/>

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_fsp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1480000"/>

           <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Discount :"/>

           <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_discount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="999999"/>

        </TableRow>
   </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: exactly what i want,but how to add spacing between columns?

Comment: By adding margin to your TextView.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code as a separate layout and include it in main layout file or use directly in main layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:text="TOTAL"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="GT : 5400000"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="FSP : 1480000"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="DIS% : 29.15%"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Discount : 9999999"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Its looks like this:
[image]

You can update the inner `TextView`s to `LinearLayout`/`RelativeLayout` if you also need to show the pop-up cloud images.

To keep complexity at minimum just use the text like "GT : GT_VALUE" in strings.xml and then `setText(getString(text_id).replace("GT_VALUE",value))`

Comment: Happy to help, but if this helped, just to help future audience, then this should be the accepted answer ;)

Comment: Actually i tried both answers but found able stuff more useful as per my design so accepted the top answer,but this is also useful :)